# systemd stuck at "Powering off." on 16.04 - Dell Latitude

Tags: 16.04, shutdown, systemd

With a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 on an old computer* that's been running 14.04 fine, Ubuntu won't fully shut down.

I've tried the fix everyone suggests, namely, changing a line in `/etc/default/grub` to be `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi=force apm=power_off"` and then running `sudo update-grub`.

I've tried shutting down from the GUI, `sudo halt`, and I think I tried `sudo poweroff`.

It ends by saying:

```
systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGKILL to remaining processes...
systemd-journald[210]: Received SIGTERM from PID 1 (systemd-shutdow).
systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGKILL to remaining processes...
systemd-shutdown[1]: Unmounting file systems.
systemd-shutdown[1]: Remounting '/' read-only with options 'errors=remount-ro,data=ordered'.
EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro,data=ordered    
systemd-shutdown[1]: Remounting '/' read-only with options 'errors=remount-ro,data=ordered'.
EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro,data=ordered
systemd-shutdown[1]: All filesystems unmounted
systemd-shutdown[1]: Deactivating swaps.
systemd-shutdown[1]: All swaps deactivated.
systemd-shutdown[1]: Detaching loop devices.
systemd-shutdown[1]: All loop devices detached.
systemd-shutdown[1]: Detaching DM devices.
systemd-shutdown[1]: All DM devices detached.
systemd-shutdown[1]: Powering off.
```

But it just sits there. After a few minutes the screen turns off and will turn back on when I press a key. I can switch to a TTY (Ctrl+Alt+F1) where it asks for a login, but won't accept any input (nothing shown when I type login name). Other TTYs just have a flashing cursor. Ctrl+Alt+Delete in a TTY does nothing, and the REISUB command appears to work until the very last key stroke (and yes, `kernel.sysrq=1`). Once I also tried `sudo swapoff -a` before shutting down.

Ideas? I tried two fresh installs of 16.04, same problem both times. Worked on 12.04 and 16.04 with a different HD. I've uploaded a couple lousy "screenshots": [bottom of screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oulsW.jpg) and [entire screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKMpv.jpg).

<sup>*Dell Latitude D630. Just upgraded to a new 2012 Intel SSD.</sup>

Comment: Have you tried updating the kernel? I had this same issue among many others with my fresh 16.04 install(s)... I installed kernel 4.5 and it all seemed to go away! Also just curious which DE you are running?

Comment: @PSmith Standard 64-bit download with Unity. I've never specifically done a kernel upgrade, though I run `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` all the time, and I believe that will take care of the kernel, correct? Everything is up to date. EDIT: Kernel is at 4.4.0-24-generic as reported by `uname -r`. Just FWI: I typed this up just before bed, which I have to head to now, but as this is the main family computer, you can be sure this is high on my priority list. I should be back in the morning. I'll look into upgrading the kernel.

Comment: I can't say for sure that it will fix your issue; mine were alleviated but I don't know if it's specifically related to that or not but I know the freezing and crashes stopped. 16.04 is still a baby, with lots of problems. Here's the link I followed, it's real easy to update. And don't remove your old kernel! Just hold `Shift` when you boot to select the new one from GRUB. http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/03/upgrade-linux-kernel-4-5-ubuntu/

Comment: @PSmith I upgraded to 4.6 but nothing seemed to change (upgrade confirmed by `uname -r `). So I installed 14.04 but I'm having the same problems, and figured out that `pci_devices` is not stopping on shutdown (I have a report from apport). Related: WiFi doesn't work either (and that's a PCI device, I think). My old install of 14.04 on another HD still works though. And now (after writing that) it shut down without a problem after doing seemingly unrelated things (trying to get wifi to work; haven't succeeded yet). Perhaps running `apt-get autoremove` removed something that was causing problems

Comment: Linux is always a great mystery, until it isn't! Glad you got it working anyway!

Comment: @PSmith Thanks for your help. I got it working in 14.04.3 and 16.04 and posted the solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to have had something to do with `pci_devices` and the WiFi. I've found a reproducible solution:

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

This works on both 14.04.3 and 16.04. I believe this is firmware for the Broadcom BCM4311 network controller. Oddly, this both fixes the WiFi* and solves "the halting problem." Once apport reported that `pci_devices` was refusing to terminate at shutdown (though it didn't always report it, even when there were shutdown problems). The WiFi controller is, by my understanding, a PCI device; hence the connection between the two issues I was facing.

For details about fixing the WiFi, see [this answer of mine.](https://askubuntu.com/a/477945/289003)

<sup>*I also purged `ndiswrapper*` and `bcmwl-kernel-source`, which are related to the WiFi, but just doing that didn't solve either problem; the installation of `firmware-b43-installer` was what fixed it, though it's unclear to me whether that by itself would have solved one or both problems.</sup>

Comment: I think I have a similar issue on an MSI WS60 laptop. The link with the PCI system sounds plausible to me as well, as doing `lspci` doesn't work either: it hangs. The proposed solution doesn't help me though.

Comment: @Bram Did you purge `ndiswrapper*` and `bcmwl-kernel-source`? The original answer I got this from is [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/419248/289003). It was an answer specifically about the Dell Latitude D630 though.

Comment: Indeed I also did those purges, but these packages weren't present anyway. And yes, I know it's a different system, but I'm trying all kinds of solutions; maybe I don't have this BCM4311.

Comment: My situation actually got much better with the nvidia driver; now `lspci` works and indeed I don't have the BCM, so I'm in the wrong place here..